# Consecutive integers which have digital sums that are not relatively prime

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory, number-property

What are ten smallest natural numbers *n*, such that *n* and *n*+1 have digital sums which are not relatively prime?

Answer (score 7):

> Compared to a natural number n, n+1 has all its digits the same except that all trailing 9s become 0s, and the last non-9 digit of n is incremented (where we implicitly include a leading zero in n). Thus if n's digital sum is d(n), d(n+1) = d(n) + 1 - 9 t(n), where t(n) is the number of trailing 9s in n.

> Clearly d(n) and d(n+1) must be coprime if t(n) = 0, since two consecutive natural numbers are always coprime. If d(n+1) is not coprime with d(n), it must share a factor greater than 1; this factor must thus also be a factor of d(n) - d(n + 1) = 9 t(n) - 1.

> For t(n) = 1, 9 t(n) - 1 = 8, so it suffices that d(n) is even. For t(n) = 2, 9 t(n) - 1 = 17, so d(n) must be a multiple of 17 (and since there must be exactly two trailing 9s, the smallest such value is 8899 with digital sum 34).

> We can easily find ten smaller naturals with only one trailing 9 and even digital sum; the ten smallest are: 19, 39, 59, 79, 109, 129, 149, 169, 189, 219.

Comment: Nice! I wonder, which is the first instance in which the common divisor is not 2.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos (39,40) has GCD of 4. If you mean odd GCD > 1, it is only possible when you go to x99 -> (x+1)00 (difference 17) or x999 -> (x+1)000 (difference 26), the smallest possible such number being (8899,8900).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, all consecutive integers are relatively prime. Thus, we must look at

> places where the digital sums of integers are nonconsecutive. Specifically, we look at *n* ending with 9:
>
>  **19, 20** (sums: 10, 2)
>  **39, 40** (12, 4)
>  **79, 80** (16, 8)
>  **109, 110** (10, 2)
>  **129, 130** (12, 4)
>  **169, 170** (16, 8)
>  **219, 220** (12, 4)
>  **259, 260** (16, 8)
>  **309, 310** (12, 4)
>  **349, 350** (16, 8)

Comment: you're absolutely right on both counts lol. I'm not sure how I got mixed up on the first sentence, and I think at some point I switched "relatively prime" for "divisible" in my head. oh well. I've edited the first sentence, and since T. Linnell already got the right answer, I'll leave the rest unchanged